# How can I format an interval type in Jasper

Tags: java, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have a query to returning a column that is postgres "interval" type. How can I format this field to show the duration as HH:mm? I tried a few different types for the Expression Class like java.lang.String java.util.Date and java.sql.Timestamp and set HH:mm in the Pattern property but it always just outputs like this

0 years 0 mons 0 
days 1 hours 30 
mins 0.00 secs

Also tried `new SimpleDateFormat("MM:mm").format($F{duration})`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval` type so the available methods are getMinutes(), getHours() etc.

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/PGInterval.html